# Android: Currently Displayed Layout(s) file name(s)

Tags: android, testing, layout

How to get the name of the currently used Layout(s) file name(s) ?
for example it could be res/layout/main.xml or something like that.
Also, the code which require this information is not part of the app that contains this layout, it's kind of a testing code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Internally Android doesn't refer to them by filenames, it refers to them by id-  an integer.  You can see the integer it uses in your generated R file.  And that information isn't stored, it inflates the proper file then forgets about it.

Comment: I can't access the R file, because i'm not doing this from the application as I said.

Comment: and this is perfectly possible, Otherwise, How did they make the hierarchyviewer anyway?
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

i assume, you can go with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and lots of iteration.

First you want all your statics in the R.layout class - then you obtain their values and compare them to the `View.getId()` and in a last step you retrieve the fields name.

but: the name will only contain layout-files name (in your example `main`) and not the full path to it, even though you could have duplicate layouts with the same name, e.g. for landscape/portrait mode etc

I never tried something like that and I'm not sure if this works out, because i don't know if your testenvironment can access your R file without errors, but that's the way you could go

edit: just adding some sample code that should do the job, works from within the app - as said i'm unsure about your framework and the way you access r

```
R.layout layout = new R.layout();
Map<Integer, String> id2name = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (Field f : layout.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    try {
        id2name.put(f.getInt(layout), f.getName());
        Log.i("Layout", f.getInt(layout) + "," +  f.getName());
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //oops
        Log.e("Layout", "", e);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        //oops
        Log.e("Layout", "", e);
    }
}
for (Entry<Integer, String> e:id2name.entrySet()) {
    if (findViewById(e.getKey()) != null) {
        Log.i("Layout:", "found: " + e.getValue() + ";" + e.getKey());
    }else {
        Log.i("Layout:", "not found: " + e.getValue()+ ";" + e.getKey());
    }
}
```

note that there will be no view found unless layouting is done (findViewById() is null if you call to early)

of course you can go the other way around and search down the view tree by checking if a layout is instance of a ViewGroup and iterate over its childviews and compare each's id to the ids in the map